# Loading of imported classes of loaded classes using Reflection in Java

Tags: java, exception, reflection

I am trying to load classes from a jar file. Basically, I want to call a method in a particular class in a package of that jar. The problem I am facing here is that after the class is successfully loaded from the jar and when I try to instantiate I get exception : ClassNotFound for classes imported in my class.

Here is the class which loads the class:

inputs: D:\Myjar.jar , com.vendor.epbroker.VNFLCMCommunicator

```
public Class<?> loadClass(String libPath, String pkgName) {
        LogManager.getLogger().info("Adding Class");

        File jarFile = null;
        try {
            jarFile = new File(libPath);
            URL fileURL = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
            String jarURL = "jar:" + fileURL + "!/";
            URL urls[] = { new URL(jarURL) };
            URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            Class<?> beanClass = ucl.loadClass(pkgName);
            ucl.close();

            return beanClass;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogManager.getLogger().error("Given Library: " + libPath + " or Class name: " + pkgName + " is not Valid");
            LogManager.getLogger().error("Exception occurred : ", ex);
        }

        LogManager.getLogger().error("Class loading Error: Returning NULL");
        return null;
    }
```

The code snippet which receives this Class:

```
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();

                // To get the list of methods exist in the Class
Method[] listOfMethods = classToLoad.getMethods();
```

The following error is encountered:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/vnflcm] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vendor/epbroker/exception/EPBrokerException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vendor.epbroker.exception.EPBrokerException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Remove your `String jarURL = …` line.  The URL should not be a "jar:" URL at all.  Just do `URL urls[] = { fileURL };`.

Comment: @VGR This did not help either. Execution of this still gave the same error. And besides the error was for com.google.gson.Gson and for classes in other packages as well. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: You say the error occurred when you tried to load com.google.gson.Gson, but the exception says it failed to find com.vendor.epbroker.exception.EPBrokerException.  Is EPBrokerException.class in your .jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following lines:

```
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> beanClass = ucl.loadClass(pkgName);
ucl.close();
```

and consider the documentation of [`URLClassLoader.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close--):

> Closes this URLClassLoader, so that it can no longer be used to load new classes or resources that are defined by this loader.

In other words, you should only close a class loader if you are really done using the classes of that loader. Even if all required classes had already been loaded at this point, there was still the possibility that a required resource needs to be accessed. Note that some frameworks have there own reflection library requiring access to the byte code of the classes, which will be accesses like a resource.

In your specific case, it’s even simpler. You have just loaded one class, which only triggered resolving of the required minimum set of classes (e.g. the direct super class), but no other dependencies. Then you close the class loader, preventing subsequent loading of any other class from your jar file, which hits you when resolving the constructors needs resolving more referenced classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few considerations you have to take when trying to use `Reflection`.

1. Your URLClassLoader must contain the URL of the jar that you want to reflect into.
2. If the desired jar depends on any other jars, you must load the URLs for those jars as well.
3. As @VGR pointed out, you cannot simply use the file path for the jar to use as a URL. One thing you can do is :

   ```
    File myJar = new File("path/to/myJar.jar");
    URL myJarUrl = myJar.toURI().toURL();
   ```

A simple example to demonstrate the issue:

Let's call your jar myToolProject. And let's say while developing this tool you created a class, call it `JsonMaker`, that converts a POJO to a JSON and you accomplish this via the `gson.jar`. When you build your jar, let's call it myjar.jar, you mention that in the manifest that it depends on gson.

When trying to reflect on myjar, you reflect on each class in your jar, until you reach `JsonMaker.class`. When trying to reflect here we notice that there is `com.google.Gson` type object here. The URLClassLoader looks through the URLS in its array and tries to find `com.google.Gson` in some class. If it cannot find any `com.google.Gson` class, it cannot reflect on that class, and throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.